# Cannot Find Symbol error for method

Tags: java, file, passwords

im having problem with the code. I need to read data from a txtfile. User will input his username and password , and the system will check with the information stored in the textfile for verificaiton , once it is successful he will be logged in. But im having a error which im not sure how to proceed.

```
public class existingCustomers {

    String username, password;

    public existingCustomers() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Kreg Hotel booking System");
        System.out.println("Please login.");
        System.out.println("==============================================");
        System.out.println("Username: ");
        username = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Password: ");
        password = input.nextLine();
        new userPassOk(username, password);
    }

    private boolean userPassOk(String user, String pass) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("customerinfo.txt"));
        username = user;
        password = pass;
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] userPass = s.nextLine().split(":");
            if (userPass[0].equals(user) && userPass[1].equals(pass))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My error is

```
C:\Users\MegaStore\Desktop\java testing\existingCustomers.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        new userPassOk(username,password);
            ^
  symbol:   class userPassOk
  location: class existingCustomers
1 error
```

Comment: also, storing **unencrypted passwords** in **plain text** in a file is just a data breach and lawsuit waiting to happen.

Comment: I doubt that this will ever be in a production system. After fixing the error in the question, the next problem will be the `FileNotFoundException`. It is obviously written by someone who doesn't know Java.

Answer (score 3):

`userPassOk` is not a [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html), it's a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html); so you shouldn't be calling it by using `new`.

Since it returns a `boolean`, you'll want to use it in a conditional like so:

```
if(userPassOk(username, password))
{
  // My logic here!
} else {
  // No entry for you!
}
```

Comment: That comment wasn't meant to you I'm sorry. @ Heng Aik Hwee should go learn the principle of OOP before asking something obvious like this.

Answer (score 0):

the compile error tells you exactly where the problem is, right on line 18.

you have `new userPassOk`

`userPassOk` is not a class, it is a method.  remove new, and it will compile.

it won't **work** but it will compile...